# module 'freud' has no attribute 'voronoi'

Tags: python, attributes

I am trying to generate VORONOI plot for my system.
I am very naive to python and I am using Freud analysis library for computing Voronoi.
For checking if the sample code is running on my machine, I tried running the sample code of the website for which following is the link:
https://freud.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0/examples/module_intros/Voronoi-Voronoi.html

When I am running the code it generates an error saying:

> AttributeError: module 'freud' has no attribute 'voronoi'

I compiled the code both using terminal and jupyter notebook.

Comment: `freud.voronoi.Voronoi` existed in Freud 0.81. But in later versions it appears instead to be called `freud.locality.Voronoi`. Check the version you have installed and look for corresponding documentation. https://freud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/examples/module_intros/locality.Voronoi.html

Comment: In the link which you provided, I tried executing the code, it again reports an error:
AttributeError: module 'freud' has no attribute 'box'

Comment: Did you change the call as documented for the version of `freud` that you are running? It appears that the doc you are following is outdated and your code won't work as expected with later versions.

Comment: Yes I changed the call as per the documentation:

L = 2
box = freud.box.Box.square(L)
voro = freud.locality.Voronoi()

But the problem still remains. Kindly suggest some methods if I am using the outdated documentation.

Comment: Did you get *precisely the same* error message or another one? Did it say `AttributeError: module 'freud' has no attribute 'locality'` or something else? Sometimes one line of code can have 2 or 3 or more errors in it, and fixing the first only turns up another message about the next one.

Comment: I got the following error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 L = 2
----> 2 box = freud.box.Box.square(L)
      3 voro = freud.locality.Voronoi()

AttributeError: module 'freud' has no attribute 'box'

Comment: As I suspected, that is a completely different error at a different point in the code. You are either going to have to find a more up-to-date tutorial than the one you are following, or be prepared to look more deeply into the software as it is currently documented. I'm sorry if this seems harsh advice, but SO is a Q/A site. The format is not suited to handholding a beginner trying to use obsolete tutorial material that presents code that no loger works. We can help you with your own code that doesn't do what you expect. We can't help you fix broken code you didn’t write and don't understand.

Comment: Hi, 
I tried code with the latest documentation and succeeded a bit. 
The code seems to work for few of my systems, although for some cases, the code abruptly terminates and shows the following message:

Duplicate: 1142 (18.72,8.6,0) matches 95 (18.72,8.6,0)

I searched for this occurrence but I am not able to find a satisfactory answer.

Following is the link which I am referring:

https://freud.readthedocs.io/en/v2.10.0/gettingstarted/examples/module_intros/locality.Voronoi.html

Comment: That is an entirely different problem arising from different code and apparently has to do with data. Please post a fresh question with the code as it now stands, the error message you now get including traceback, and a sample of the data. A Stack Overflow question is not suited to an ongoing dialogue that has a drifting topic.